# Как отобразить огромную картинку, которая не влезает в оперативную память?

Tags: c#

Есть 100500 картинок, которые я хочу склеить в одну и отобразить. 
Проблема в огромных размерах этой картинки. 
Хотелось сжимать ее до FullHd, но иметь возможность при приближении повысить четкость. 
Т.е. примерно как в гугл картах.

Есть ли какие-то идеи как это реализовать? Может быть есть какие-то библиотеки?

Comment: Можно реализовать как в гугл-картах. Каждый масштаб режется на кусочки небольшого размера, и подгружаются только те, которые видны на экране.

Comment: Я [давно](https://github.com/tym32167/LeafletMapSample) что то [подобное](https://rawgit.com/tym32167/LeafletMapSample/master/index.html) делал. [https://leafletjs.com/](https://leafletjs.com/) вам в помощь, но это для веба для JS

Comment: Спасибо за советы. Буду пробовать)